# How can I add two sin waves of different amplitude and frequency?

Tags: trigonometry, frequency

I've been tearing up the internet, but I can only find explanations for adding two sine waves of same amplitude and frequency, two sine waves of different amplitudes, or two sine waves of different frequency but ***not*** two sin waves of different amplitude and frequency.
I've tried;

```
Abs[(E^(I (f0 - f1) t) + ar) ]

Abs[Sin[f0 t] + ar Sin[f1 t]]

Sqrt[(1 + ar Cos[f1 - f0])^2 + (ar Sin[f1 - f0])^2]Sin[f0 t + ArcTan[(ar Sin[f1 - f0])/(1 + ar Cos[f1 - f0])]]
```

but none of these provide the answer I need. I'm about to go insane, can anyone help?

Comment: Unclear what you want. The sum of two sine waves at different frequency is not a sine wave.

Comment: @JohnDoty But it is a wave, and I need that wave. Unless I'm just entirely off course.

Comment: The wave is `a Sin[something]+b Sin[something else]`. There really isn't a simpler way.

Comment: @JohnDoty Shoot, I omitted that that was my first attempt. I've got a test case it doesn't meet though. For the values f0 = 115, f1 = 122, ar = 0.7 and t = 2.1 I need to produce ~0.665. The simple formula produces -0.299.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a Sin[b π t] + c Sin[d π t], 
  {t, -1/2, 1/2}], 
  {{a, .5}, 0, 1}, 
  {{b, 115}, 100, 130}, 
  {{c, .5}, 0, 1}, 
  {{d, 122}, 100, 140}]
```

Comment: I tried this formula, but I do not get the results I need. I've got a test case where f1=115, f2 = 122, ar = 0.7, and t = 3.2. I need 0.411, I get 0.102.

Comment: @user3501859:  I'm sorry, but you're simply confused at such a level I don't think we can help you.  You want a plot, but "check" your answer at a single value of $t$; you "mix" two sine waves but give the amplitude of only one component; and so on.  You need to speak with your instructor.

Comment: I think you're the one who's confused haha, I didn't need a plot I needed to match a value. In the code I'd posted I'd forgotten to add pi, identifying that was the solution.

Comment: "but not two sin waves of different amplitude and frequency."  Well... $a \sin (2 \pi f_1 t) + b \sin (2 \pi f_2 t)$.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be I'd neglected to put pi into the sines.

Bad: Sin[f t]

Good: Sin[f pi t]

Comment: A full cycle is `2 Pi` radians, so for the common definition of "frequency", the sine wave is `Sin[ 2 Pi f t]`.